# What is the advantage of a do-while(false)?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

When looking through some code that was handled by another employee, I see a lot of code written in:

```
do{
    ...
}while(false);
```

What advantage (if any) does this provide?

Here is more of a skeleton that is happening in the code:

```
try{
    do{
        // Set some variables

        for(...) {
            if(...) break;
            // Do some more stuff
            if(...) break;
            // Do some more stuff
        }
    }while(false);
}catch(Exception e) { 
    // Exception handling 
}
```

**Update:**

> **C++ Version:**
>   [Are do-while-false loops common?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412081/are-do-while-false-loops-common)

Comment: the main advantage is it tells you the other employee needs talking to!

Comment: Why the close vote? This is *totally* a real question!

Comment: looks totally loopy to me....

Comment: another employee? as in someone that you work next to? and can possibly talk to? and might get an answer from?

Comment: @kdgregory: Sorry, I should have said ex-employee. I cannot contact him. But all of his code is wrapped in this.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Actually, it doesn't look loopy at all (pun intended!) ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412081/am-i-the-only-one-who-does-this

Comment: @erickson what's common practice in one language isn't necessarily common practice in another.

Comment: Duplicate or not, I found this question (and the answers) quite instructive. Thanks for a good question.

Comment: maybe the coder was using it for narrowing local variable scope, not realizing you could do the same thing with bare {}.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Maybe it was done to be able to jump out of the "loop" at any time, e.g:

```
do
{
    ...
    if (somethingIsWrong) break;
    //more code
    ...
}
while(false);
```

But as others have said, I wouldn't do it like this.

Comment: Yeah, let's hack around the fact that our language doesn't have `goto`!

Comment: I considered this, but given that a simple `if` statement (or horror, a `goto`) would do the job much more simply, I doubt it somewhat.

Comment: Wow - it's a Java-style goto! (but it's begging to be a function with a conditional return instead...)

Comment: @mmyers: it more or less the same as (ab-)using exceptions for flow control

Comment: Although you don't need it in Java as you can label the loop.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the only way to make this more convoluted is to use a try {} finally {} block somewhere in between.  This code makes me sad.

Comment: moonshadow: Why would abusing return be any better? You would be splitting the existing method at possibly a very awkward point.

Comment: Noldorin: If there are multiple `if`-`breaks`, the equivalent `if` tree would be disappearing off the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: @Tom, because you *know* in what method you are when you see that *return*. But if you see a "break", you usually think "oh, that's breaking out of the loop - wait, LOOP??", it is just confusing i think.

Comment: In the OPs question the break is breaking out of an inner for loop and not the do while loop.

Comment: @fortran: Yes, for values of "has" equaling "will recognize and give a compile error if you use".

Comment: @mmeyers I see that this is the current behaviour, but I'd swear that long, long time ago, when I had my first programming classes at the university (circa 2000), a fellow student surprised the teachers using `goto` in a Java assignment xD... I have to research if early Java 1.1 really supported that or I am being tricked by my memory.

Answer (score 17):

In Java, there is no reason to do this.

In C, this is a common idiom when defining macros:

Consider:

```
#define macro1 doStuff(); doOtherStuff()
#define macro2 do{ doStuff(); doOtherStuff(); } while( false )

if( something ) macro1; // only the first statement in macro1 is executed conditionally
if( something ) macro2; // does what it looks like it does
```

...but macros in C are evil and should be avoided if at all possible.

Does your coworker come from a C background?

Answer (score 14):

No advantage. Don't do it.

Comment: It has the advantage of enraging mmyers.  Isn't that reason enough to do it?

Comment: I'm not enraged. Then again, I don't have to maintain this guy's code.

Comment: you *should* be enraged. Didn't you see his while loops! ;)

Answer (score 7):

It can be used to goto the end of a block which can be used to avoid a bunch nested if/then blocks.

```
do {
    if (done()) continue;
    // do a bunch of stuff
    if (done()) continue;
    // do a bunch more stuff
    if (done()) continue;
    // do even more stuff
} while (false);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is used in C to define block inside macro. See [this](http://www.noveltheory.com/TechPapers/while.htm) for example.

Example, the following is invalid:

```
#define f(x) { g(x); h(x); }

if (x >= 0) f(x); else f(-x);
```

but with this definition, it will work:

```
#define f(x) do { g(x); h(x) } while(false)
```

Comment: Java doesn't have macros, and if it did having a semicolon following a closing brace is legal in Java, so it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Having semicolon is legal unless you want to put 'else' there.
if () {}; else {} - is illegal

Comment: You might want to expand on that.

Comment: This seems like the most logical explanation, and backs up @moonshadow.

Answer (score 3):

It is useless, but the coder could have used a multiple break commands to do some weird exception handling.

```
do{
if(<something>){...}else{break}
if(<something else>){...}else{break}
...
}while(false)
```

Granted its stupid, but I did find something like in a old c program once

Comment: Just ran into this today. Found this construct in the body of a C++ method and wondered, WTF? Google led me here and this seems the most likely answer. The original coder had multiple if (errorCond) { /* do something */ break; } statements within the do..while block. The only advantage I can see is that provides one point of return from the method (at the end of the method, as is the case in the code I'm staring at) rather than several. I wouldn't code it that way, but I can see why it was done.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is right. That is a completely useless thing to do.

It is *possible* that whoever coded it originally had something other than `false` as the condition, and simply changed it to `false` rather than removing the entire block not to lose this "history" of the code. This is a just clutching at straws however. To be quite frank it's just a plain example of a [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28rhetoric%29), which has no place in code.

Comment: Woah, what's with the sudden down-votes? It is courtesy to leave a comment when you down-vote, and the reason has not already been explained!

Comment: +1 to get your post upwards again. However, i can imagine some people are confused by your analogy with "logical tautology" and think that you talk about "false" being a tautology. Can you please elaborate on that analogy?

Comment: @litb: Cheers. And yeah, I used the wrong sort of tautology there perhaps. It is certainly a tautology in the common sense of the word: the fact that you write the code once, then add `do { ... } while (false)` again (unnecessarily) specifies that it should be added once.

Answer (score 1):

In pretty much every language other than C/C++ this provides no tactical advantage.

In C/C++ there is a case with macros where do/while(false) makes it easier to expand a macro safely into multiple statements.  This is advantageous when the macro otherwise looks like a normal function call.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412081/am-i-the-only-one-who-does-this)

The OP asks about this exact construct and explains some reasons for using it.  The consensus seems to be that it's a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

As a placeholder for a future when some other condition is put in place of `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be used to skip execution of some code (like a `goto` or something) but when I look at it again, there seems to be a `for` loop (where the `if(...) break;` statements are) in the `do-while`. Otherwise, I would say that it would be a Java version of a `goto`...

Answer (score 1):

I've used this convention for years!  It's most useful when you have a "pipeline" of processing and/or conditional checks.  It simply avoids multiple levels of nested if() statements and thus makes the code (much) easier to read.  Yes there are alternatives like try/catch and I only use this style in certain thin/lower-level situations.

I start the "loop" (never actually loops) with a comment like...

```
// Error loop (never loops)
```

The error-loop is...

```
set errorCode = fail;
do {
  if (this)
    break;

  if (that)
    break;

  // Success
  set errorCode = ok;

  // Alternative Success
  errorCode = doWhatever();
} while (false);
```

Consider this style if you have a bunch of nested if() statements and your indents go more than 3 levels deep.

I've used this convention in Perl, C/C++, Java and Delphi/Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess the author of that didn't trust his code so he used to run it a couple times to see if that made it work more and this is the archeological remains of that.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is to create a block to make variables declared within the `{...}` more tightly scoped, but there are better ways of doing this (like creating functions, or just creating blocks - hat tip to Pete Kirkham).

Comment: Yeah, though personally I find random blocks in code an eyesore.

Comment: Surely `do ... while (false)` are not just an eyesore but a brainsore too?

Comment: @dtsazza - Agreed. I'm not suggesting this is a good way to code, just that it might be what the developer was doing originally, though I confess I find Martin's suggestion more compelling.