# why those two points are php tips?

Tags: php, structure, continue

i'm reading a blog that give something php coding tips.there are two places I don't understand.

1. less/not use continue.
2. the structure :

   ```
   do{
     if(true) {
          break;
     }
     if(true) {
          break;
     }
   } while(false);
   ```

   is better than :

   ```
   if(true) {
   } else if(true) {
   } else {
   }
   ```

can somebody explain why ?

Comment: The if block isn't even necessary.

Comment: Does it pertain to how PHP handles the `if` and `do`? Write a readable code... PHP should perform the right optimizations to make no difference between the two structures - if it does not, it should/will. A link to the tips?

Comment: Any optimization tips like these should be ignored. I'm sorry you wasted your time reading that blog.

Comment: Regarding question 2: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445025/what-is-the-advantage-of-a-do-whilefalse . It's got nothing to do with PHP specifically, it's just a pseudo-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt this as a `do { } while ()` is checked every iteration, whereas an `if` is just a simple comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the point they were trying to demonstrate in the blog is that a do {} while() loop will pause your code until a condition is met, where as the if statements will be parsed and your code will continue regardless of whether the condition is met or not.